# Arangodb cursors system fields

Tags: arangodb

is it possible to **not** return key / system fields when returning a cursor? I'm using ArangoDB for an open data portal. I want to offer an API so my users can query datasets; _key,_rev and _id are irrelevant to them.

eg `{"query":"for x in collection limit 10 return x","sysFields":false}`

I've got a wrapper api in place so it would be possible for me to remove them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AQL provides a function [ATTRIBUTES()](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/AQL/Functions/Document.html#attributes) to return all top-level attributes of a given document, with an optional parameter to omit system fields (every attribute key that starts with an underscore), which can be used in combination with the `KEEP()` function to get rid of system fields:

```
FOR x IN collection
LIMIT 10
RETURN KEEP(x, ATTRIBUTES(x, true))
```

Comment: Excellent a bit of regex server side to substitute this if the query is a simple "return x". Now you've got me thinking I can provide a simple UI for beginners to help them build a query.

Comment: You may wanna check out [Foxx](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Foxx/), which you can use to create custom endpoints to e.g. remove certain attributes before handing it out.